# Loops in MySQL alone

Tags: mysql

I'd like to select from one table and use the results of that select to update another table, but only based on certain conditions.  Is this possible with a 1-time SQL query?

Comment: Do you want us to just say "yes" in an answer???  Perhaps you'd like to flesh out your question a bit more.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Can you give a concrete example? Otherwise you'll probably just get a link to the manual which some contains examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

```
UPDATE
  tableToUpdate AS ttu
[LEFT|RIGHT|INNER] JOIN
  otherTable AS ot
ON 
  joinCondition
SET
  ttu.field = ot.field
WHERE
  conditionsToBeMet
```

AS `otherTable` you can just use the `SELECT` query that you use to fetch your resultset.